# how to use htaccess redirectmatch with query_string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

im trying to redirect `"search.php?q=somethinghere"` to `"search/somethinghere/"` but I can't do it! I'm trying to send form "`<form action="search/" method="get" name="search">`" like this but url goes to `"search/?q=somethinghere"`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/search.php?q=(.*)$ http://domain.com/search/$1/` this is also not working. whats the problem?

I don't want "?q=" in URL.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a typo above the problem is that you're trying to redirect:

```
^/search.php?q=(.*)$
```

but the URL you're receiving is:

```
search/?q=somethinghere
```

(the difference is the .php in your redirect rule)

You may want to try using the following redirect rule instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/search?q=(.*)$ http://domain.com/search/$1/
```

Comment: but i want to cut out "?q=" things.. understand?

Comment: Try this: 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/search/?q=(.*)$ http://domain.com/search/$1/

The issue is that you're looking for something different than what you're getting.  There's no ".php" in your request, so your rule is going to miss it.

Comment: Sorry, looks like the something in my previous comment got eaten.  I'll edit the post to include what I would recommend suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much cleaner and faster to do it on the client side. Have Javascript construct the `search/query` URL on form submit - that will save you an extra request.

However, to do it through server-side redirects, you can use `mod_rewrite` with `RewriteCond` and `QUERY_STRING` as the source:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  \bq=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^search.php$ /search/%1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Make sure you use [R=301] to do a proper redirect including changing the URL. I edited that a minute after posting so you might have copied the older version.

Comment: with your updated code url becomes: http://domain.com/search/nero?q=nero "?q=" still here :((

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for anyone this may help, I think you need to put a `?` at the end of the RewriteRule to clear the query string, eg: `RewriteRule ^search.php$ /search/%1? [R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have .htaccess questions, I always take a look at this site first: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php#cooldenial

The site provides a lot of examples and explanations for doing different things with .htaccess files. According to that site you could try something like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+) http://domain.com/search.php?q=$1 [NC]
```

However, I'm not an .htaccess guru - so you may need to fiddle with it.